# Google Distance matrix how to upgrade quota request

Tags: google-maps, google-distancematrix-api, google-directions-api

i want to calculate the distance between 100 x 100 = 10000 using google distance matrix. and i always enable billing with standard usage but continues to give the error **OVER_QUERY_LIMIT** 
i always check the limits:
1) 2500 / days but i enable the billing 
2) 100 elements per seconds, i insert an interval of 5 seconds on client side 
 
3) 100 elements per query i always have a 25 elements of destination and 1 for origin

i am working on javascript with jquery

```
var origin_vertices = [{ lat: 44.1101790, lng: 12.4232134} ......,{ lat: 45.9859019, lng: 112.6167280}]; // 100 elements
var number_of_split = 4;
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
var my_origin = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(origin_vertices)); 
var origin_dict = [];

for (var i =0; i < my_origin.length; ++i){
    var my_dest = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(origin_vertices)); 
    var temp_origin = [];
    temp_origin[0] = my_origin[i];  

    for (var j = 0; j < number_of_split; ++j){ 
        var split_array = my_dest.splice(0, 25);
        origin_dict.push({origin: temp_origin, destination: split_array})
    }
} 

// after this operations i have a vector of 400 elements, with 1 origin and 25 destination

var dim_new_array = origin_dict.length;  
var i = 0; 
var interval = setInterval(function() { 
    orig = origin_dict[i].origin;
    dest = origin_dict[i].destination;  
    callservice(orig, dest); 
    i++;  
    if(dim_new_array <= i){ 
        clearInterval(interval);
    }  
}, 3000);

function  callservice(orig, dest){
    // serve solo per chiamae la API
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: orig,
        destinations: dest,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,//DRIVING, BICYCLING, WALKING, TRANSIT
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,//IMPERIAL
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    }, Callback);//  service
}
```

i am use only distance service.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I put my code @geocodezip

Answer (score 0):

As you have already mentioned that you enabled billing; I would suggest two steps to make sure you've got everything configured correctly.

1. Make sure the project which you enabled billing for is the same project you're making reaching this quota limit from.
2. Visit the Quotas tab and configure these settings so they allow a higher quota. These settings can be found at API Manager > Library > Google Maps Distance Matrix API > Quotas (or [try this link](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/distance-matrix-backend.googleapis.com/quotas))

Comment: yes, the project and api-key  is same. Elements per day = 4.735 / 100.000, Elements per 100 seconds per user = — / illimitato, Elements per 100 seconds = — / 10.000

Comment: Sorry I could not be of help. Consider using the free Google Support Forums.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a list of origin and destination and you go down by the list each time calculation will be proceed for the given values also. so here we need to freeze the value when we get instead of formula we need on edit function with array formula

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).